# Azure Eventhub capture functionality and how to replay

Tags: kafka-consumer-api, azure-eventhub

What exactly is azure eventhub capture . Is it a mechanism to have infinite retention of events in a persistent storage like Azure blobs inside a storage account in the form of avro/parquet  ? If so how do i replay these events (those captured in azure storage via eventhub capture) from beginning using a normal kafka consumer . Any help appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To tackle your particular situation -  No you can't use a regular kafka consumer to replay eventhub capture data (which is usually stored as an avro file in a blob storage container). You can maybe write something to push these messages back into an eventhub to consume them, or just consume them directly

Answer (score 0):

What do you want in short, your question is not clear. explain a little on replay these events

Comment: Hello ,The premium tier for eventhubs supports message retention of 90 days.I publish 100 messages to eventhub on 25th July 2022 for the first time .Assume my requirement is to to get all these events published on and after  25th July after 1 year,let's say 25 July 2023  For sure it will not be available in eventhub based on 90 day retention policy .Would eventhub capture be of any use here ? Also i am using kafka endpoints to interact with eventhub . With normal kafka broker i could use `auto.reset.offset=from-beginning` on the consumer . But i dont think this will work with eventhub capture

Answer (score 0):

Basically Event Hub capture is storage for your events beyond retention. Please read through this FAQ, which might clear your doubt.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/event-hubs/event-hubs-faq#what-is-the-maximum-retention-period-for-events-

You can find your data in the captured blob even after retention periods and then use data processing engines to process it.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/event-hubs/explore-captured-avro-files
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/event-hubs/event-hubs-capture-python

Comment: Thank you , but this is unlike kafka . Although eventhub supports kafka protocol , we cannot process these avro files using a normal kafka consumer , and write another component to process these if i want to replay the data , right ?